# Will EmojiCompat automatically get new glyphs in new Android versions?

Tags: android, emoji

[EmojiCompat documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html) doesn't mention for the case of "Bundled font" whether the provided emoji are tied to the specific package version you include.

If I integrate `BundledEmojiCompatConfig` v26 will it render new emoji in Android 27 without upgrading the app? Or will we have to update the package dependency and release a new APK?

Answer (score 0):

> "If I integrate BundledEmojiCompatConfig v26 will it render new emoji
>   in Android 27 without upgrading the app"

No it won't. Bundled version puts the font in your app, therefore you will have to update to the new library version and build a new apk.

If you want automatic updates you should use FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig which downloads the font from the server (once per device, not app)